# ActiveMQ and prefetch limit

Tags: jms, activemq-classic, spring-jms

I want to understand how ApacheMQ's prefetch limit works. Are all the messages sent in one burst? What if there are concurrent consumers, what happens then?

What is the difference between prefetch limit of 0 and 1?

Comment: Did you even search for some answers? http://activemq.apache.org/what-is-the-prefetch-limit-for.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read [the link recommended by @Tim Bish](http://activemq.apache.org/what-is-the-prefetch-limit-for.html) -- the quotes I offer are from that page.

> So ActiveMQ uses a prefetch limit on how many messages can be streamed
>   to a consumer at any point in time. Once the prefetch limit is
>   reached, no more messages are dispatched to the consumer until the
>   consumer starts sending back acknowledgements of messages (to indicate
>   that the message has been processed). The actual prefetch limit value
>   can be specified on a per consumer basis.

Specifically on the 0 versus 1 prefetch limit difference:

> If you have very few messages and each message takes a very long time
>   to process you might want to set the prefetch value to 1 so that a
>   consumer is given one message at a time. Specifying a prefetch limit
>   of zero means the consumer will poll for more messages, one at a time,
>   instead of the message being pushed to the consumer.